# Detect Incoming Bluetooth Share?

Tags: android, bluetooth

How can i detect that my device is currently receiving a file via bluetooth , and when the 
transfer is completed.

I want my app to check the bluetooth folder after transfer to see if a particular file was sent over via bluetooth.

I cant seem to find any intent for use with broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

You can check https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/master/src/com/android/bluetooth/opp/BluetoothOppReceiver.java

`BluetoothOppReceiver` is a broadcast receiver that registers such broadcasts.
For example,

`Constants.ACTION_INCOMING_FILE_CONFIRM` is used when you get request to accept or decline incoming file.
`BluetoothShare.TRANSFER_COMPLETED_ACTION` can be used when transfer of file is complete.